# check db file is exist or not?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, cross-platform

I want to create a shared template in which I want to check the SQLite database file is exists or not, and if the file does not exist then create a new DB file in xamarin.

//my function

```
 public Task<CreateDatabase> DbConnection(string DbName, string DbPath)
    {
        string dbname = DbName.ToLowerInvariant();


        string path = Path.Combine(DbPath, dbname);

        var database = new CreateDatabase(path);

        if (File.Exists(path) == false)
        {
            
            var database = new CreateDatabase(path);
            

        }
                    
        return null;
    }
```

properties

```
 public class CreateDatabase
{
    public string databasePaths { get; }

    public CreateDatabase(string databasePath)
    {
        databasePaths = databasePath;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Flags` to check and create the database if the database doesn't exist.

```
 public static class Constants
{

    public const SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags Flags =
        // open the database in read/write mode
        SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite |
        // create the database if it doesn't exist
        SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.Create |
        // enable multi-threaded database access
        SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache;      
}
```

And then set the `Flags` when you build the connection.

```
Database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Constants.DatabasePath, Constants.Flags);
```

You could download the sample code form the link below for reference.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/todo/

Comment: sir, i want to implement this in crossplatform.plugin.template not in xamarin template.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-473885.PluginForXamarinTemplates&ssr=false#overview It seems for Visual Studio 2017. I use Visual Studio 2019 with the latest version. When you use the template, is there any errors?